# In .NET WinForms, how do I put controls in the window border like IE8, WMP, Win Explorer etc.?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Using WPF, how do I put controls in the window border, like the address bar of IE8, the play controls in Windows Media Player, and the address bar of Win. Explorer?

Comment: Are you using WPF *or* WinForms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using WinForms, take a look at:

- [Windows Vista Aero Glass in .NET](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17681/Windows-Vista-Aero-Glass-in-NET-Managed-Win32-Appl)
- [Windows Vista Aero Pt. 1 - Adding Glass to a Windows Forms Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tims/windows-vista-aero-pt-1-adding-glass-to-a-windows-forms-application)

If you're using WPF, take a look at:

- [Aero Glass inside a WPF Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adam_nathan/aero-glass-inside-a-wpf-window)
- [How to extend the Aero Glass into the Client area](https://www.wpftutorial.net/ExtendGlass.html)